# When is $ u v^* \succeq 0$, for two complex vectors $u$ and $v$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, positive-semidefinite

It seems like maybe $u$ has to equal $v$, or maybe $ u = cv $ for some $ c > 0 $. Is this true?

If $ u v^* $ is positive semidefinite, then $ x^* u v^* x \ge 0$. I observe then that $ x^* u v^* x = (x^* u) (v^* x)$, the product of two inner products. If this is greater than equal to zero, then the two inner products must always have the same sign, for all $x$. Geometrically, this means $u$ and $v$ are always "pointing in the same direction" as $x$, for all $x$ (or both pointing "away" from $x$). I think this implies necessarily that $ u = cv $ for some $ c > 0 $. If not, we could choose an $x$ pointing in the same direction as $u$ but not $v$, and then $ (x^* u) (v^* x) < 0 $, violating the positive semidefinite condition.

Comment: $\succeq 0$ makes little sense for non-Hermitian matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the matrix annihilates the orthogonal complement of $v,$ and sends $v$ itself to a positive multiple of $u.$ It's adjoint annihilates everything orthogonal to $u$ and sends $u$ itself to a positive multiple of $v.$ So, the matrix is only self-adjoint when $u$ is a real multiple of $v,$ and only PSD if the multiple is positive. In which case it is just a positive multiple of the projection onto the subspace generated by $u$ (or $v$ if you prefer).

Comment: thank you. unfortunately i'm not familiar with what annihilate, orthogonal complement, and adjoint mean but will look them up.